# Error when invoking WCF service from the client

Tags: wcf

I've a WCF service project and client project in my VS.Net 2008 solution.
When running the client, am getting this error:

> Could not connect to http:// localhost:8000/Services/TestService. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000

What am i missing over here? How do I make sure that my service is running?

Comment: Your service is most probably not running or service host failed to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WCF test client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to test your service.

Answer (score 1):

Is this possibly due to the `DisableLoopbackCheck` registry setting?

[WCF: Calling WCF service hosted in IIS on the same machine as client throws authentication error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/11/10/wcf-calling-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis-on-the-same-machine-as-client-throws-an-authentication-error.aspx)